# Global filters with parameter dependencies in .net core 5

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-5.0

I have a validation filter. I want to register it as global level. But in the ConfigureServices method i can not assign the dependencies of it. Is there any efficient way to do it.
Here is my code.

My filter.

```
public class ModelValidationFilterAttribute : Attribute, IAsyncActionFilter
{
    public ILogger<ModelValidationFilterAttribute> logger { get; }
    public ModelValidationFilterAttribute(ILogger<ModelValidationFilterAttribute> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(context.ModelState);
        }
        await next.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Extension method

```
    public static IServiceCollection CustomServices(this IServiceCollection services)
    {            
        services.AddScoped<ModelValidationFilterAttribute>();
        return services;
    }
```

In ConfigureServices method

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {   
        services.CustomServices();         
        services.AddControllers(options =>
        { 
            options.Filters.Add(new ModelValidationFilterAttribute());
        });           
        
    }
```

Code works fine if i register it on controller or action level with attribute. But when i try to register it on service level it doesn't take the argument.

Comment: I have many services that's why i don't want to mess with my startup class. But this is not my answer i think.

Comment: Please see the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-6.0#dependency-injection)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of adding this as a filter , add a filter as service. It will do the magic.

`options.Filters.AddService<ModelValidationFilterAttribute>();`